# Visual Studio 2010 dll create error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am new to C# programming and I have a problem with dll creation.

I opened a class library project and write public static methods in my classes. Clicked debug and copied dll and pdb files (under bin/debug/..) to my WPF application project.

I didn't get any reference problems also editor shows my methods normally, also when I use them it gives me no error or warning...

However, when I run my program, I saw that my methods calling dll methods are not working. In addition, debug mode also jumps my methods so I cant trace the code.

Where am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to create dll or am I missing a trick in here?
Thank you..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the calling methods are not working?  The debug mode is jumping your methods because the debugger is unable to locate the source.  Attach the dll solution to the same project, and reference the output of the dll, that should solve that problem.'

Comment: i recommend: don't copy your DLL and pdb files. in your WPF project, add a reference to your library DLL and when you build your WPF project, it should automatically create the DLL and pdb files in your output dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than copying the DLLs into your WPF app's bin directory, you should either add a *project* reference to your class library from your WPF app, or add a reference to the output directory of the class library. Otherwise the build is probably copying over your hand-copied files. Basically, you should treat anything in bin as "controlled by Visual Studio" IMO - don't copy anything there manually. It helps if you use project references rather than referring to specific files, too - that way each build gets an appropriate configuration for its dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I click add project reference I get empty list. Should I merge these two projects in one solution?
If I should, there is a problem. WPF application is written by four people including me and my codes in dll must only be visible by me. We are using svn and committing entire solution. I dont know how to hid code if I didnt compile my code and just add reference

Comment: @ErcanÖzdemir: It wasn't clear that they weren't in the same solution. Why would you want to hide your source code from your colleagues? If you're using svn, can't they see your code anyway? If you *really* need them in different solutions, I suggest you have a "lib" directory or something where you copy your library to, and then add a reference to *that*.

Comment: one of our group member is outside of the company so some methods (including decryption, authentication etc.) needs to be hidden. Creating a lib directory and copy dll in it is my first try. I referenced dll in my WPF project but my methods are not working even though I get no error

Comment: @ErcanÖzdemir: Okay, then it sounds like you'll need to just publish the binary. "Not working" is a pretty vague description of what's happening though. If there are no errors (including no exceptions) then *something* must be executing...

Comment: OK, let me try to be more clear (Sorry, I am new in developing C#, therefore I am having a hard time explaning my problems)

        public string example()
        {
            String hardwareKey = KeyManager.generateHardwareKey("", macAdress);
            return hardwareKey;
        }

I set a debug point at first line of this method debugger jumps my method. (KeyManager is in my dll and it has public static methods)

Comment: @ErcanÖzdemir: Rowland's guess sounds right to me - what value is returned?

Comment: It seems that something in my method (generateHardwareKey) causes this problem. I moved my all methods to WPF application but it is still not working. Also, other methods in my dll are working well. So thank you all for your answer